# Laravel - Using scope

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I am using scope to specify if i am not an admin, then return courses only by instructor. What I am trying to do is when an instructor signs into their account they can only view the course they have been assigned to teach.. I am unsure where i have gone wrong in my query.. it is throwing no errors so i know it has not broke it.. which is a good thing? But my query is not displaying the results I need. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your instructor relation doesn't have user_id because it is in your pivot table.

Try this inner query: `$q->where('id', Auth::user()->id);`

Comment: thank you for your reply.. but unfortunately it has not made any change

Comment: Then check what is returned by `Auth::user()->isAdmin()`

Comment: what do you mean? Sorry I am new to laravel

Comment: User model has to have isAdmin method. Ant there has to be logic that returns true if user has admin rights and false if it doesn't. So to can add `dd(Auth::user()->isAdmin());` before your if ()...

Comment: I do not have isAdmin method in user model, it is in my course model?

Comment: so how did you add `if(!Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {` this line ? i think you have to learn more about laravel.

Comment: Thanks for your input , but everyone has to learn from somewhere. Putting others down will not make you feel any better about yourself.

Comment: i'm not putting you down. You have to think abour every line what ir does and how it work when you copying it from tutorials... these comments is not for learning you. I see that you still don't know basics of php object oriented programming. Good lock