# Laravel - my scope method does not appear to be working

Tags: php, laravel, scope

I am using scope to filter conditions for specific users, I have assigned a course to a teacher and when this teacher signs into their account, I only want this teacher to view their course, although my scope method doesn't appear to be working correctly. I am not getting an error, so I am not sure where I have gone wrong. I have added some of my code below, i would be very grateful for any help. Thanks

CoursesController index method;

```
 public function index()
    {
        $courses = Course::ofTeacher()->get();

        return view('admin.courses.index')->with('course', $courses); //pass data down to view
    }
```

Course.php;

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'title'
    ];

    public function courses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    } 

 public function teachers() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'course_user')
   }

   public function scopeOfTeacher($query)
        {
            if (!Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
                return $query->whereHas('teachers', function($q) {
                    $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
                });
            }
            return $query;
        }
    }
```

User.php;

```
public function isAdmin() {

    return $this->role()->where('role_id', 1)->first();
}
```

Comment: Please give more details about "doesn't appear to be working correctly. I am not getting an error".

Comment: Probably the answer for this question is in Zak's yesterdays question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60623026/laravel-using-scope/60623807?noredirect=1#comment107256116_60623807
You have to use: `$q->where('id', Auth::user()->id);` because your teachers relation is users table ant it doesn't have user_id column

Comment: And also your isAdmin method has to return boolean value. not Role model.